# What does loadable mean in microcontrollers in the sense of linikers

Tags: gcc, linker, arm, cortex-m

I'm trying to get familiar with the linking and startup procedures in ARM Cortex-M4 microcontrollers. Looking through the linker scripts almost all the sections are marked as loadable.

At first I thought that meant it would be copied from flash to RAM, but then I learned that doing that is handled in a different way. So what does it mean for a section in flash to be loadable? Isn't it already loaded and run from the location in flash? Also, I'm referring to a section section containing instructions.

Does loadable in this context mean loading by the debugger into the device?

Comment: non-loadable sections are those that for example contain symbols for debugging

Comment: anything that gets used by the program itself is loadable, .text, .rodata, .data, .bss, etc.

Comment: what file format, I assume you mean elf?  (which is not specific to microcontrollers btw, used with operating systems as well)

Comment: Yes, elf. I'm confused when you mark a section as loadable, what does that mean? Where is it loading from, and where is it loading to?

Comment: for a microcontroller that depends on the software you are using to ideally download the program into the flash.  some software only likes raw binary images (arm-whatever-objcopy myprog.elf -O binary myprog.bin), some can read elf, ihex, srec, coff, or other file formats and extract the relevant items from those formats and download those bytes into the flash.

Answer (score 3):

a fully functional cortex-m program

flash.s

```
.thumb

.thumb_func
.global _start
_start:
stacktop: .word 0x20001000
.word reset
.word hang
.word hang

.thumb_func
reset:
    bl notmain
    b hang

.thumb_func
hang:   b .
.align

.thumb_func
.globl dummy
dummy:
    bx lr
```

so.c

```
void dummy ( unsigned int );
int notmain ( void )
{
    unsigned int ra;

    for(ra=0;ra<10;ra++) dummy(ra);
    return(0);
}
```

flash.ld
    MEMORY
    {
        rom : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
        ram : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
    }

```
SECTIONS
{
    .text : { *(.text*) } > rom
    .rodata : { *(.rodata*) } > rom
    .bss : { *(.bss*) } > ram
}
```

build

```
arm-none-eabi-as --warn --fatal-warnings -mcpu=cortex-m0 flash.s -o flash.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc -Wall  -O2 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -ffreestanding -mthumb -c so.c -o so.o
arm-none-eabi-ld -o so.elf -T flash.ld flash.o so.o
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D so.elf > so.list
arm-none-eabi-objcopy so.elf so.bin -O binary
```

(can use cortex-m4 either works)

so.list

```
00000000 <_start>:
   0:   20001000    andcs   r1, r0, r0
   4:   00000011    andeq   r0, r0, r1, lsl r0
   8:   00000017    andeq   r0, r0, r7, lsl r0
   c:   00000017    andeq   r0, r0, r7, lsl r0

00000010 <reset>:
  10:   f000 f804   bl  1c <notmain>
  14:   e7ff        b.n 16 <hang>

00000016 <hang>:
  16:   e7fe        b.n 16 <hang>

00000018 <dummy>:
  18:   4770        bx  lr
  1a:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)

0000001c <notmain>:
  1c:   b510        push    {r4, lr}
  1e:   2400        movs    r4, #0
  20:   0020        movs    r0, r4
  22:   3401        adds    r4, #1
  24:   f7ff fff8   bl  18 <dummy>
  28:   2c0a        cmp r4, #10
  2a:   d1f9        bne.n   20 <notmain+0x4>
  2c:   2000        movs    r0, #0
  2e:   bc10        pop {r4}
  30:   bc02        pop {r1}
  32:   4708        bx  r1
```

being a less complicated linker script and program the elf has less stuff

part of readelf

```
Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .text             PROGBITS        00000000 010000 000034 00  AX  0   0  4
  [ 2] .ARM.attributes   ARM_ATTRIBUTES  00000000 010034 00002d 00      0   0  1
  [ 3] .comment          PROGBITS        00000000 010061 000011 01  MS  0   0  1
  [ 4] .symtab           SYMTAB          00000000 010074 0000f0 10      5  12  4
  [ 5] .strtab           STRTAB          00000000 010164 00003d 00      0   0  1
  [ 6] .shstrtab         STRTAB          00000000 0101a1 00003a 00      0   0  1
Key to Flags:
  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings), I (info),
  L (link order), O (extra OS processing required), G (group), T (TLS),
  C (compressed), x (unknown), o (OS specific), E (exclude),
  y (purecode), p (processor specific)

There are no section groups in this file.

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr   PhysAddr   FileSiz MemSiz  Flg Align
  LOAD           0x010000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00034 0x00034 R E 0x10000
```

hexdump -C so.bin

```
00000000  00 10 00 20 11 00 00 00  17 00 00 00 17 00 00 00  |... ............|
00000010  00 f0 04 f8 ff e7 fe e7  70 47 c0 46 10 b5 00 24  |........pG.F...$|
00000020  20 00 01 34 ff f7 f8 ff  0a 2c f9 d1 00 20 10 bc  | ..4.....,... ..|
00000030  02 bc 08 47                                       |...G|
00000034
```

a "binary" comes in many flavors, it is an unfortunately poorly named term as it is so confusing.  Everything you see in the disassembly above is required for the program to run, that is the real binary part of this, it has to be loaded wherever you need it loaded to run.  if on an operating system then the operating system reads the elf file extracts the loadable sections with their addresses/offsets and loads them into memory before launching at the entry point.  Take advantage of tools already having the elf file format and we can re-use some of that for microcontrollers, we cant/dont normally use the entry point as that makes no sense, we have to make the vector/entry point match what the hardware needs, in this case a vector table.

The hexdump coming from the objcopy also shows the parts we have to have visible to the processor for the program to run, or loaded in address/memory space (flash is in memory or address space in this case).

But the "binary" file, the elf also contains debug symbols in case you want to pull up a debugger, add some more options on the toolchain command line and you get even more information about where these items are in the source code file so you could in some cases see the high level langauge when single stepping through code.  Those are not loadable sections, they are descriptive of the program or just there to help out, they are not machine code nor data that the processor needs to execute the program so they do not need to be loaded into the memory space.

yet another "binary" file format

```
arm-none-eabi-objcopy so.elf -O ihex so.hex
cat so.hex 
:100000000010002011000000170000001700000081
:1000100000F004F8FFE7FEE77047C04610B5002483
:1000200020000134FFF7F8FF0A2CF9D1002010BCA2
:0400300002BC0847BF
:00000001FF
```

it has a little extra information but almost all of it is the part we have to load into the address space for the program to run

another binary file format

```
S00A0000736F2E7372656338
S1130000001000201100000017000000170000007D
S113001000F004F8FFE7FEE77047C04610B500247F
S113002020000134FFF7F8FF0A2CF9D1002010BC9E
S107003002BC0847BB
S9030000FC
```

also most of it is program.

elf is just another file format (fairly popular with gnu tools, but still just another file format), it contains the machine code and data required plus a bunch of other stuff, the machine code and data is what we have to load into ram if this is an operating system, or what we ideally load into flash for a microcontroller, but not all microcontrollers are equal some are ram only based and the program is downloaded via usb during enumeration (into ram).  and other solutions, or if debugging you could probably have items loaded into ram depending on the mcu and tools, although that is not how the thing boots so that wouldnt really be a good binary.

if you feel the need to zero .bss and to have any .data then you need additional information, the offset and size of .bss and the offset and contents of .data, the bootstrap then zeros and copies those items, and you need that information in the non-volatile flash/rom, it is just more data that is required of the machine code and data needed to run the program.  If you are letting others write the code for you then there are possibly tailored linker scripts and bootstrap code that allows you to just have .data items and push a build button on a gui and it all magically is in place when your entry point (main() by convention and or standard) starts execution or the code that represents your high level code at the C entry point.

Comment: if you are using the gnu tools you have everything you need to examine what is going on you can disassemble the objects and see how they contribute to the final program.  the elf file format is pretty easy to parse can write your own program to parse if you feel inclined, a 30 minute project.  can see the older and still used intel hex or motorola srecord formats, just look those up on wikipedia to see what is going on there, clearly the advantage over a raw memory image file is if you have different sections of data that are not-linear you dont have to pad, you can jump to

Comment: around in space as there is a starting address per line of data.

Comment: you can see in the readelf dump that the actual program is marked AX and that is what needs to be in the device, I could add .bss or other and make the program bigger and it might create new sections that are also required to be (loaded) in the device.

Comment: also the symbol table is shown in the readelf dump, names of labels and such in case you wanted to lets say...disassemble the program (objdump -D) and end up with some labels instead of raw addresses...(clearly not required to be in the device in order to run, not loadable).

Comment: Just as a side question: why are the memory cells behind stacktop (carrying seemingly the addresses for the `start` and `hang` labels) off by 1? The ELF says those labels are at 10 and 16 respectively, no?

Comment: it is tied to the bx/blx instruction and extended beyond that.  Arm instructions are 32 bit, 32 bit aligned, thumb instructions are one or two 16 bit halfwords, halfword aligned.  so the lsbit is always zero.  they used the lsbit to indicate thumb mode when using an instruction like bx.  The lsbit is consumed and placed in the cpsr (thumb bit) as well as used to stay in or switch modes.  Then for whatever reason this vector table works the same way even though this is clearly a cortex-m thumb only.  So historically it makes sense, but exactly  "why" is a question for ARM.

Comment: as a label to a function they are orred with one, as an actual address that instructions are fetched from the lsbit is zero.